# encrypted external luks disk, permissions and label

Tags: permissions, mount, encryption, luks

I followed this tutorial to encrypt my external disk: https://ncona.com/2016/07/encrypting-an-external-drive-using-luks/

now I have 2 problems. Although I chose a name for the disk with 
    `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 mydisk`

its not mounted with this name, but with a random string like
    `luks-ewqqoiwu01209412k1234532`

How can I set a label to the disk, that is saved with the disk and not only for my computer?

Then there is the permission problem. Only root has write access to the disk. I can change that for my computer with 
    `sudo chown -R adrian /run/media/anovelo/e2902cbe-7e2d-4fb2-8cfe-f50ba9b80795/`

That might work for my computer, but how can I achieve, that it is automatically writable by normal user when connected to a computer? Why is it not like a normal unencrypted disk?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use

```
e2label /dev/mapper/mydisk label-of-your-choice
```

to set the label of the encrypted filesystem. However, that will only be visible after the encrypted partition is opened. As for the luks partition, I don't think it's possible to set a label on those.

(Note that `e2label` is applicable to ext2/3/4 fs only, other fs have different utilities.)